# Contentful api - getting images

Tags: javascript, api, contentful

I am new to contentful API but so far getting content from the API has been pretty straight forward.  I have created a new space using their "blog" template and I see that in the "body" field there is an "insert media" button.  I don't think I get how this is supposed to be used.  When I insert an image into the "body" field, it generates a code that doesn't get rendered when I pull the content form the API.  I am using a markdown parser to render the text.  If you create an entry with images, these images will be available as an asset.  Do I need to make a separate API call for every asset I want rendered with my entry?

Answer (score -1):

When you use the Insert Media button, it should generate something such as:

```
![Lewis Carroll](//images.contentful.com/zz2okzf5k4px/2ReMHJhXoAcy4AyamgsgwQ/ec4998388330a939288c04558c57477a/lewis-carroll-1.jpg)
```

That url points to the image directly, so you don't need to do any extra calls to get the asset. The asset is an entity which contains metadata as well as the url to the asset file itself, but in this case you already have that url.

You said you are rendering the Markdown, maybe there's a problem in the code that gets generated? Could you post that?